# Counting many to one relationship in Core Data

Tags: swift, ios, core-data, swiftui

I tried to create simple application, yet I encountered problem with relationship using Core Data in SwiftUI.

I have 2 simple models, `ParentEntity`:

```
public class ParentEntity: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ParentEntity> {
        NSFetchRequest<ParentEntity>(entityName: "ParentEntity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var children: NSSet?

    var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? "Unknown"
    }
    
    var wrappedChildren: [ChildEntity] {
        if let children = children as? Set<ChildEntity> {
            return children.sorted { $0.wrappedName < $1.wrappedName }
        }
        return []
    }

    // MARK: Generated accessors for children

    @objc(addChildrenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChildren(_ value: ChildEntity)

    @objc(removeChildrenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChildren(_ value: ChildEntity)

    @objc(addChildren:)
    @NSManaged public func addToChildren(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeChildren:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromChildren(_ values: NSSet)
}
```

`ChildEntity`:

```swift
public class ChildEntity: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    static func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ChildEntity> {
        NSFetchRequest<ChildEntity>(entityName: "ChildEntity")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var flag: Bool
    @NSManaged public var value: Int32
    @NSManaged public var parent: ParentEntity?

    var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? "Unknown"
    }

    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get {
            Int(value)
        }
        set {
            value = Int32(newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

There is many-to-one relationship in `ParentEntity` that I wanted to make use in my UI. Basically what I try to achieve is `List` with tiles consist of `name` of the `Parent` and both numbers of flagged and unflagged children. At first I wanted to use `children` (or rather `wrappedChildren`) property of `ParentEntity`, but with that approach I had a problem with numbers not refreshing after change in detail view. To make them refresh I created *workaround* and instead of using `ParentEntity` properties, I just make requests to obtain `ChildEntity`s of given `ParentEntity`. That's works great, but I'm worried about scalability of such solution when there are more `ParentEntity`s (with a lot of `ChildEntity`s *inside* each). Here is how it looks right now:

```
struct ParentsView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ParentEntity.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default
    )
    private var parents: FetchedResults<ParentEntity>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(parents) { parent in
                    NavigationLink(value: parent) {
                        ParentTile(parent)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Parents")
            .navigationDestination(for: ParentEntity.self) { parent in
                ParentDetailView(parent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ParentTile: View {
    @ObservedObject private var parent: ParentEntity
    @FetchRequest private var children: FetchedResults<ChildEntity>

    private var totalChildrenCount: Int {
        children.count
    }

    private var flaggedChildrenCount: Int {
        children.filter(\.flag).count
    }

    init(_ parent: ParentEntity) {
        _parent = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: parent)
        let fetchRequest = ChildEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = []
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(ChildEntity.parent), parent)
        _children = FetchRequest(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            animation: .default
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(parent.wrappedName)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(flaggedChildrenCount) / \(totalChildrenCount)")
            }
            ProgressView(value: Float(flaggedChildrenCount), total: Float(totalChildrenCount))
                .progressViewStyle(.linear)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ParentDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var parent: ParentEntity
    @State private var childToEdit: ChildEntity?

    init(_ parent: ParentEntity) {
        _parent = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: parent)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(parent.wrappedChildren) { child in
                ChildrenTile(child)
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button {
                            childToEdit = child
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(parent.wrappedName)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .sheet(item: $childToEdit) { child in
            ChildDetailView(child)
                .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ChildrenTile: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject private var child: ChildEntity

    init(_ child: ChildEntity) {
        _child = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: child)
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    child.flag.toggle()
                    do {
                        try viewContext.saveIfNeeded()
                    } catch {}
                }
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: child.flag ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
            }
            Text(child.wrappedName)
            Spacer()
            Text(child.wrappedValue, format: .number)
        }
    }
}
```

Is this approach acceptable? Or maybe I could use `ParentEntity` property and still get proper results somehow?